# USB - multiple file copy

Tags: performance, usb

I am trying to copy a file to my flash drive. Lets say it takes about 5 minutes.

When i try to copy the same file to 'n' serial devices one by one, it takes about '5n' minutes.

Can the file copy be broadcasted to 'n' devices simultaneously such that i can copy the file to 'n' devices in the duration of 5 minutes ?!

Comment: What do you mean by "serial devices"?

Comment: Hi David , by "serial devices" I mean "flash drives".

Comment: OK, that is not the usual term.  Mass Storage Device is the term to use from the USB specification.  Thumb drive or flash drive are good colloquial terms.  While USB technically is a serial protocol, if you say "serial devices" people usually think of RS-232 and similar protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably reduce your copying time by plugging the USB flash drives (also known as Mass Storage Devices) into as many different USB controllers as you can.  Some computers have multiple USB controllers that each handle the communication on some number of USB ports.  If you plug two flash drives into the same USB controller, I think they will probably be competing with eachother for bandwidth on the bus.

If you are using Windows, you can go to the Device Manager and in the "View" menu select "Devices by connection" in order to see your USB controllers and how they relate to the devices you have plugged in.